# HAL-style rendering issues with spring-hateoas

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

This time I'm really confused and stuck...
I'm working on a spring-boot (1.5.3) application exposing a REST API with HAL style using spring-hateoas library. Some of the endpoints already work correctly and return HAL-links. Currently I'm trying to change another endpoint to also return the response with HAL, but the result is serialized in the `"collection+json"` style.

What I found so far:
There are 3 `ObjectMapper` instances in the spring context:

- `objectMapper`
- `_halObjectMapper`
- `halObjectMapper`

I converted the response with all three of these and found that the first two produce `"collection+json"` output (`"links"` with `"rel"`) and the third one produces the expected HAL style (`"_links"` without `"rel"`).

Why are there three and how can I inspect and control which of these objectMappers get used for rendering the response? How is it possible that my other endpoints return the expected format?

---

Here's my simplified code, in case it's of any interest:

```
@RestController
public class SearchController{

    @RequestMapping(value = "/search", produces = { "application/hal+json" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<SearchResponse> search(...){
        SearchResponse searchResponse = ...; // search & build response
        return new ResponseEntity<>(searchResponse, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

public class SearchResponse {

    @JsonProperty("_meta")
    private PageSortInfo meta;

    @JsonUnwrapped
    private Resources<Resource<SearchResultItem>> resultlist;

    ...// getters & setters
}
```

The response is supposed to look like this:

```
{
    "_meta" : {
      ...
    },
    "_embedded" : {
      "searchResultItemList" : [ {
        ...,
        "_links" : {
          "self" : {
            "href" : "..."
          }
        }
      },
      ...
      ]
    },
    "_links" : {
      "self" : {
        "href" : "http://localhost:8882/api/search"
      }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after another day of digging through google search results, sprint-boot code and a lot of trial & error I finally found the answer, which is of course trivial:

Spring will choose the `MessageConverter` used to convert the response object to the appropriate format by matching the registered converters to the type of the object (in my case `SearchResponse`) and the response type (`"application/hal+json"` for me). The `halJacksonHttpMessageConverter` will only be chosen if the response object is of type `ResourceSupport`. SO all I had to do is make my `SearchResponse` extend `ResourceSupport` and I got the expected response format.

```
public class SearchResponse extends ResourceSupport {...}
```